# Null exception in android 4.1 but working in 4.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Well I have this
in xml

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinnerLanguages"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />
```

and In Fragment code file

I have inflated in oncreate

```
viewInflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, null);
```

and

```
spinnerLanguages = (Spinner) viewInflate.findViewById(R.id.spinnerLanguages);

String[] items1 = new String[] {"lang1", "lang2", "lang3","lang4"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items1);
spinnerLanguages.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But i am getting Null exception in this line

```
spinnerLanguages.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in jellybean(4.1) but it is working fine in 4.2+

**How can i solve this problem?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are probably giving different version of the layout file  *fragment_search.xml* in your layout-vx directories**: check how many *fragment_search.xml* exist in your layour directories (*e.g. inside layout-v17 vs. layout or layout-v16*).

Comment: Exactly there was layout-large folder and i was testing in tablet so it was causing all problem not the version different. Thanks. I have done most of the OO languages i found java is too cry baby in terms null handling. Plus that error message is so misguiding.Can't be they more informative and accurate. I was thinking it was not able to handle null values from database. Any ways thank you. Solved my problem.